# Fastest way to run calculations on a list of lists

Tags: python-2.7, numpy, numba

I have a list of lists like so:

```
import numpy as np
import random
import time
import itertools

N = 1000
x =np.random.random((N,N))
y = np.zeros((N,N))
z = np.random.random((N,N))

list_of_lists = [[x, y], [y,z], [z,x]]
```

and for each sublist I want to calculate the number of non zeros, the mean and the standard deviation.

I have done that like so:

```
distribution = []
alb_mean = []
alb_std = []


start = time.time()

for i in range(len(list_of_lists)):

    one_mean = []
    non_zero_l = []
    one_list = list_of_lists[i]

    for n in one_list:


        #count non_zeros
        non_zero_count = np.count_nonzero(n)
        non_zero_l.append(non_zero_count)

        #assign nans
        n = n.astype(float)
        n[n == 0.0] = np.nan

        #flatten the matrix
        n = np.array(n.flatten())
        one_mean.append(n)

    #append means and stds
    distribution.append(sum(non_zero_l))
    alb_mean.append(np.nanmean(one_mean))
    alb_std.append(np.nanstd(one_mean))


end = time.time()
print "Loop took {} seconds".format((end - start))
```

which takes 0.23 seconds.

I tried to make this faster with a second option:

```
distribution = []
alb_mean = []
alb_std = []


start = time.time()

for i in range(len(list_of_lists)):

    for_mean = []

    #get one list
    one_list = list_of_lists[i]

    #flatten the list
    chain = itertools.chain(*one_list)
    flat = list(chain)

    #count non_zeros
    non_zero_count = np.count_nonzero(flat)
    distribution.append(non_zero_count)

    #remove zeros
    remove_zero = np.setdiff1d(flat ,[0.0])
    alb_mean.append(np.nanmean(remove_zero))
    alb_std.append(np.nanstd(remove_zero))

end = time.time()
print "Loop took {} seconds".format((end - start))
```

which is actually slower and takes 0.88 seconds.

The sheer amount of loops has me thinking there is a better way to do this.  I have tried `numba` but it doesn't seam to like appending in a function.

Comment: Why are you using *numpy functions* on a list-of-lists? Why not use a `numpy` array?

Comment: forgive me as I am new to the world of numpy, but I am doing things as I am because the data in the list of lists represents numpy 2d matrixes

Comment: Won't it be better to have an input array of `ints` with zeros. Currently, with `np.random.random((N,N))`, its very unlikely to have any zeros, so computations like `np.count_nonzero(n)` are redundant.

Comment: In my real data there are 0's, perhaps I should have chosen a better example matrix

Comment: Try `np.random.randint()` maybe.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Version #1**

Well in your sample with the loopy solution, you are looping with two loops - One with `3` iterations and another with `2` iterations. So, it's already close to being a vectorized one. The only bottlenecks being the `append` steps.

Going fully vectorized, here's one approach -

```
a = np.array(list_of_lists, dtype=float)
zm = a!=0
avgs = np.einsum('ijkl,ijkl->i',zm,a)/zm.sum(axis=(1,2,3)).astype(float)

a[~zm] = np.nan
stds = np.nanstd(a, axis=(1,2,3))
```

Using the same setup as in the question, here's what I get on timings -

```
Loop took 0.150925159454 seconds
Proposed solution took 0.121352910995 seconds
```

**Version #2**

We could compute `std` using `average`, thus re-use `avgs` for further boost :

[image]

Thus, a modified version would be -

```
a = np.asarray(list_of_lists)
zm = a!=0
N = zm.sum(axis=(1,2,3)).astype(float)
avgs = np.einsum('ijkl,ijkl->i',zm,a)/N

diffs = ((a-avgs[:,None,None,None])**2)
stds = np.sqrt(np.einsum('ijkl,ijkl->i',zm,diffs)/N)
```

Updated timings -

```
Loop took 0.155035018921 seconds
Proposed solution took 0.0648851394653 seconds
```